# Why can't use the WMP.Lib directory in VS Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am unable to use the Windows Media Player library in vs code, despite it being referenced in the csproj and the program working when I open it in Visual Studio. I am using c# in the .net framework.

I created a program that creates a radio queue of multiple songs and then plays them. I created this program in Visual Studio on another computer and then moved it over to my personal one. VS Code is my more preferred IDE, so I wanted to work on it in VS Code, but it won't let me run it as it can't find the WMP.Lib type (CS0246). I cannot find the WMPLib.dll file in my system32 folder, but Visual Studio runs the program fine, so I don't think that's the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.